# Shouldn't this connect to firebase local emulator rather than the production server?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have a flutter app that uses firebase.
There is a specific class I would like to try hence I want to use local firestorm emulator for this class.
When the class is initialized, I am trying the below code, but for some reason, the connection is still directly to the production server.
The /hello document is created in the production server rather than in the emulator.

```
if (bool.fromEnvironment('dart.vm.product') == false) {
  final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  db.useFirestoreEmulator(host, 8050);

  db.settings =
      const Settings(persistenceEnabled: false, sslEnabled: false);

  db.doc('hello/1').set({'text': 1});
  print(db.settings);
}
```

Isn't this suppose to connect to the local emulator instead?

Comment: How do you set up emulator?

Comment: @PeterKoltai....I don't understand what you mean. The emulator is running @port ```"firestore": {
      "port": 8050
    }```

Comment: I still do not get why there is no detailed documentation concerning Flutter + Firebase Emulator...

Answer (score 0):

I use the following the connect to local Firestore emulator, and it works:

```
if (!kIsWeb) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = Settings(
      host: (Platform.isAndroid ? '10.0.2.2' : 'localhost') + ':8080',
      sslEnabled: false,
      persistenceEnabled: false);
}
```

Notes:

1. I know the docs suggest the method you try to use, but I had problem with that, and the above code worked for me. There can be a better solution.
2. Put this code immediately after calling `await Firebase.initializeApp();`.
3. I am not sure with the recently introduced Dart-only init, but in a project a few month ago the above did not work for web platform. I had to add this to the script in index.html: `firebase.firestore().useEmulator('localhost', 8080);`.

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Strange, it works for me. I guess your emulator is running, right? Can you access local Firestore using emulator UI?

Comment: yes sure. I have the emulator ui up. I can add documents manually.

Comment: And I guess you already have tried to rebuild, restart the app.

Comment: I am having this exact problem and I've figured something out. your piece of code just worked magically ONLY when attached before runApp, but when you switch `persistenceEnabled` to true, then the magic will be gone. so the piece that makes your code work rather than the `FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator` method, is that your code turns presistence off. a solution including `FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator` would be to also add a line `if (!kIsWeb) {FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings = FirebaseFirestore.instance.settings.copyWith(persistenceEnabled: false);}`

Comment: one more note, this code has to be applied EXACTLY right after calling Firebase.initializeApp (awaiting it)

Comment: @Adnan Thank you for your comment. I am calling `Firebase.initializeApp` in `main` function (with async / await). At the end of `main` I call `runApp`, and during the main widget's initialisation I use the code above to initalize emulator. It works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work for me for some reason, I had to put it right before `runApp`